# SQL Server : multiple transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

```
select 
    STUDIO.NAME, MOVIE.TITLE, MOVIE.YEAR
from 
    STUDIO 
join 
    MOVIE on STUDIO.NAME = MOVIE.STUDIONAME
where 
    MOVIE.YEAR >= ALL (select MOVIE.YEAR from MOVIE)
```

I have this code which give me as a result the year of the last film, it's title and the name of the studio, which make the movie.

How can I rewrite this code, so I can get the last produced movie by each studio, not only by one?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT a.NAME,
       a.TITLE,
       a.YEAR
FROM (select s.NAME, 
       m.TITLE, 
       m.YEAR,
       ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY s.NAME ORDER BY m.YEAR DESC ) as rnk
from STUDIO s
join MOVIE m on s.NAME = m.STUDIONAME) a
WHERE a.rnk = 1
```

Comment: elegant and scary. Any issues with transactions in this query ? ;-)

Comment: with which transactions :) row_number function works very well then you need find max per group or something similar.

Comment: Justin, I am simply not sure too. But. Could you please test the code above trying following: BEGIN TRAN UPDATE STUDIO SET NAME = ''; 

Then in other session while transaction is open and not committed, you code with partition. If you code will work then this is a bad thing. Otherwise (if will returns), it's really good code. 

Don't forget after all to run ROLLBACK.

Simply interesting and curious.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT STUDIO.NAME, MOVIE.TITLE, MOVIE.YEAR
from 
    STUDIO 
join 
    MOVIE on STUDIO.NAME = MOVIE.STUDIONAME
ORDER BY MOVIE.YEAR DESC
) AS newTable
GROUP BY newTable.NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is fine for finding the most recent year a studio published a movie, however if you need the title too, using that method you'll need to use some form of subselect to get the largest year (and so the most recent) by studio name, and then bring in the title based on this.

The below does both in a fairly succinct fashion using a CROSS APPLY:

```
SELECT 
S.NAME,
MM.TITLE
MM.YEAR
FROM STUDIO S
CROSS APPLY 
    (SELECT TOP 1 TITLE, YEAR FROM MOVIE M
     WHERE M.STUDIONAME = S.STUDIO
     ORDER BY M.YEAR DESC) MM
```

1st Edit: Added context
2nd Edit: Added edit notes.

Comment: Cross apply makes horrible execution plan. So be aware of it

Comment: @alerya , do you mind if I ask in what fashion? My understanding of the apply operator is that it is designed to be more efficient for use with correlated subqueries and table-valued functions than the join operator. Could you elaborate on your point above? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like

```
select 
    studio.name, 
    movie.title, 
    movie.year
from 
    studio 

    inner join movie on 
      studio.name = movie.studioname

    inner join 
    (
        select
          movie.studioname
          max(movie.year) year
        from
          movie
    ) t1 on
      t1.studioname = studio.studioname and
      t1.year = movie.year
```

Note that there are limitations to the way you have written your query:

- There could be multiple movies in the same year - which one is the latest? You would need a date column for that or something that that affect
- Also you are using varchar/chars to join on which is really bad practice since you have to do a string comparison on each match. It would be better to use id - integers - which give better performance

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean "not only by one"?

Normally you do such queries using aggregate functions:

```
select STUDIO.NAME, MOVIE.TITLE, MAX( MOVIE.YEAR )
from STUDIO 
join MOVIE on STUDIO.NAME = MOVIE.STUDIONAME
Group by STUDIO.NAME, MOVIE.TITLE
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: This will not work. If you have movie a, movie b then your group by will group on title and display both even if they are from the same studio.

Comment: Try not to only to Copy/Paste any solution from ppl who try to help you, but also to understand it.
If this is the case then just put MOVIE.STUDIONAME into group by as well as into select ...
It is not good practice at all what you do.... which is ask questions, try to find a "blind solution" and just share... minus ofwhat you dont undestand !!!